# How to perform load testing using visual studio [ 2015 Enterprise ]

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, performance-testing, load-testing

First of all i am new to testing. 
I want to perform load testing on web api's [ around 70 ]. I am using VS2015 Enterprise that comes with load testing feature but i am not aware how to use.

Steps that i want to perform  are:

```
1) Response time of the service when running a single request.

2) Memory consumption used by the service when running a single request.

3) Maximum number of concurrent requests supported by the service

4) Memory consumption used by the service when running the maximum number of concurrent requests.

5) Response time of the service when running the maximum number of concurrent requests.

6) Maximum number of concurrent requests that can be executed so that the response time is less than 2 seconds.
```

I have unit test ready for all api's. I found somewhere that i can use it for load testing, Is it true?

If need more clarification on question asked, reply back rather than downvoting the question.

Need help....

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert in load testing with Visual Studio, but you can find these links for reference to conduct performance testing with Visual Studio for both web applications and web services.

1. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-performance-testing
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182557.aspx
3. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923686.aspx

They should answer most of your questions.

Comment: The question is asking for lots of information, much more than can sensibly included in the Q&A format of Stack Overflow. As you correctly observe there are many Microsoft pages giving the information. A simple web search by the asker would have found them. Your answer here only provides links to a few of those pages and so can be considered against the rules of Stack Overflow. Answers here should be useful **without** referring to the linked pages. Please read the *"Provide context for links"* section of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer