# Web service method call performance

Tags: performance

I am working on a .NET web service. It is deployed on IIS 7.5 (Web server is Windows 2008 R2, 64 bit machine, 8 GB RAM) and it is used to send and receive data between client application and web server.

I would like to check the performance of the web service if more people are accessing at the same time. Kindly suggest some ways to simulate the number of users accessing the web service at the same time and track the performance. I would like to know how many users the web service can handle at the same time.

Thanks
Ashok

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform load testing using visual studio \[ 2015 Enterprise \]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337989/how-to-perform-load-testing-using-visual-studio-2015-enterprise)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It s helpful. Thanks, Ashok